# Mahout recommendations with categories

Tags: categories, mahout

I am a newbie of Mahout so please apologize me if I am asking something trivial. I would like to implement recommendations but the problem I am trying to address is not an easy one. 
I have items with ratings that belong to different categories (let's call them CATA, CATB...). Users can receive recommendations just for the category they are in. There are thousands of categories but each category has just one hundred items in it.

so if User1 gave a 2 stars rate on an item in CATA and 3 stars in CATB, if User2 gave a 3 stars on the same item in CATA then when he is in CATB I want to obtain the recommendation.
Is it possible to achieve this easily? Can it run real time or should it be a batch processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but, I think you want to just run recommendations as normal, and ignore category entirely. Then, when you call `Recommender.recommend()`, pass in a `Rescorer` implementation which returns `NaN` for everything except the category you want to recommend from.

Comment: Is it possible to optimize things reducing the categories to look into?

Comment: the Rescorer would increase compute time right? while I want to achieve the contrary? Maybe creating a user similarity function that considers the user similar if he has already bought something in the same category?

Comment: If you implement `IDRescorer.isFiltered()` you will increase performance since it will not even score the candidates that you are excluding to begin with.